# Insert float to date field mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am reading an excel file by php and when I get date, php script reads 41850 instead 09/09/2014. I need to save that in my mysql table as date format.

What is the best way to convert it?

Comment: how you are reading this?

Comment: There's no way to convert it. You should find out why this happens

Comment: AFAIK Excel has its own terr...ific way of encoding dates to ints in date cells. If you're using an appropriate library to read the XLS file, it will probably have a method to convert it to commonly used timestamp formats.

Comment: u_mulder - It happens because that 41850 is a valid MS Excel timestamp value, and it's perfectly possible to convert it

Comment: I am using phpExcel library

Comment: if thats phpexcel then mark baker is your man :)

Comment: Hope this helps : https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/70463

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the PHPExcel library, then you use PHPExcel's built-in functions to do the conversion

```
$unixTimestamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP(41850);
echo date('Y-m-d', $unixTimestamp);
```

and

```
$dateTimeObject = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject(41850);
echo $dateTimeObject->format('Y-m-d');
```

will convert the date to a unix timestamp value (that you can then format as you wish using date())  or to a PHP DateTime object respectively

However, if you're reading the cell value using `getValue()`, try using `getFormattedValue()` instead... unless you've set read data only to true when you loaded the file, then this will returna formatted string with the date value as it is displayed in Excel

Comment: Can you show me an example formating the date? I tried $unixTimestamp->format('Y-m-d'); after your first line and it doesn't do anything

Comment: Could you please, add an example of a timestamp? Getting from excel: 30/07/2014 6:43

Comment: `41850` is the Excel timestamp value for `30 July 2014`